# How to generate random boundary programmatically?

Tags: random, polygons

What should I read to understand how to draw programmatically random oil 'boundary' like on the picture below?

[image]

Yes, it should go from the top to the bottom and so I don't need these 'long' drops and I would like to start with pure 2d, black and white only (now shadows etc.).

Comment: What's this for?  I would guess that most artists wouldn't use any math at all to draw something like this.  (I could be wrong though.)

Comment: @littleO, I am looking for algorithm to generate similar images programmatically (corrected the question to reflect this).